# jest mocking functions without passing as a callback

Tags: node.js, tdd, bdd, jestjs

I have some code like:

```
module.exports = {
  idCheck: function(errors) {
    errors.some( (error) => {
      if (error.parentSchema.regexp === '/^((?!\\bMyId\\b).)*$/i') {
        this._recordError('IDCHECK');
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I am trying to test it using jest with this:

```
const IDCheck = require(
  './IDCheck'
);

let errors = [
  {
    parentSchema: {
      regexp: '/^((?!\\bMyId\\b).)*$/i'
    }
  }
];

describe('IDCheck', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('calls _recordError with IDCHECK', () => {
    jest.spyOn(this, '_recordError');
    IDCheck.idCheck(errors);
  });
});
```

however, when running jest, I get

> Cannot spy the _recordError property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Is there a way of mocking, testing for `_recordError()` having been called, or not called and with the correct parameter, without passing `_recordError` through as a parameter?

Comment: I think it should be `jest.spyOn(IDCheck, '_recordError')`

Comment: Nope, that gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

A few things about this line: `jest.spyOn(this, '_recordError');`

`this` has to be `IDCheck` because there is no `this` in scope since you are using arrow functions that inherit `this` if previously set (which it isn't). You can `console.log(this)` right above the line to prove that point.

`'_recordError'` is not a method of `IDCheck`. `spyOn` checks the target's methods, not methods called within it. Now if `_recordError` is a method of `IDCheck`, then you should be ok.

Finally, you basically have to return the data you want in order to verify it. There's no real way to check what was passed unless you return it.

Here's a solution I came up with that does not include some fixes you'd have to implement to fix the potential workflow flaws.

```
const IDCheck = {
  idCheck: function(errors) {
    return errors.map(error => {
      if (error.parentSchema.regexp === '/^((?!\\bMyId\\b).)*$/i') {
        return this._recordError('IDCHECK')
      }
    })
  },
  _recordError: function(data) {
    return data
  }
}

let errors = [
  {
    parentSchema: {
      regexp: '/^((?!\\bMyId\\b).)*$/i'
    }
  }
];

describe('IDCheck', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('calls _recordError with IDCHECK', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(IDCheck, '_recordError')
    const check = IDCheck.idCheck(errors).includes('IDCHECK')

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(check).toBe(true)
  });
});
```

Comment: Cheers @ReyHaynes.  Out of interest, i'm still fairly new to JS, so would you say the structure of my code is poor or that the tooling for testing is still up and coming?